# How does scala handle implicit typeclasses without instantiating a member?

Tags: scala, typeclass

I notice when I'm trying to create an instance of a fooSemigroup, in version one the anonymous function creates an instance of fooSemigroup without instantiating a member of Foo, but when I try to do this without the SAM construct, I need to create a dummy instance of foo for the SemigroupOps to pull in the implicit value `ev`.

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(x: A, y: A): A
}
case class Foo(v: Int)

// vs 1
implicit val fooSemigroup: Semigroup[Foo] = (x: Foo, y: Foo) => Foo(x.v + y.v)

// vs 2
class fooSemigroup(foo: Foo) extends Semigroup[Foo] {
  def combine(x: Foo, y: Foo) = Foo(x.v + y.v)
}
implicit val f: fooSemigroup = Foo(0)

implicit class SemigroupOps[A](x: A) {
  def +(y: A)(implicit ev: Semigroup[A]): A = ev.combine(x, y)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of implicit class

```
implicit class fooSemigroup(foo: Foo) extends Semigroup[Foo] {
  def combine(x: Foo, y: Foo) = Foo(x.v + y.v)
}
```

try implicit object

```
implicit object fooSemigroup extends Semigroup[Foo] {
  def combine(x: Foo, y: Foo) = Foo(x.v + y.v)
}
```

However as per Luis' advice favour `implicit val` instances over `implicit object` as otherwise resolution might result in `ambiguous implicit values` error, for example

```
trait SomeTrait[T] {
  def f: T
}
trait ExtendedTrait[T] extends SomeTrait[T] {
  def g: T
}
implicit object SomeStringObject extends SomeTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from object f"
}
implicit object ExtendedStringObject extends ExtendedTrait[String] {
  override def f: String = "from extended obj f"
  override def g: String = "from extended obj g"
}

implicitly[SomeTrait[String]] // Error: ambiguous implicit values
```

where full error states

```
Error:(15, 77) ambiguous implicit values:
 both object ExtendedStringObject in class A$A7 of type A$A7.this.ExtendedStringObject.type
 and object SomeStringObject in class A$A7 of type A$A7.this.SomeStringObject.type
 match expected type A$A7.this.SomeTrait[String]
def get$$instance$$res0 = /* ###worksheet### generated $$end$$ */ implicitly[SomeTrait[String]];}
                                                                            ^
```

Comment: why does the lambda get converted to object instead of class?

Comment: Never use `implicit object` use an `implicit val` with an explicit type signature! [here](https://github.com/BalmungSan/scala-functional-programming-tutorial/blob/master/scala-intro/src/main/scala/co/edu/eafit/dis/progfun/scala/intro/ImplicitsNotes.scala) you can find an example of why that is wrong.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Thanks Luis, I was not aware of this. Beauty of scala is there is always something to learn :) I saw `implicit object` being used in [SLS](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html#the-implicit-modifier) so I assumed it is OK.